# C++ Allocate Memory 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays

I get a `stack overflow` error because of setting a large array. I'm not sure how to allocate memory for this 2D array here, I just can't seem to get the syntax right. I used a vector previously which worked fine but I NEED to use an array for this. This code of nested loops populates the array.

```
static const int n = 607800;
int vars = 3;

array<int, vars> inputs[n];
//int *inputs = (int*)malloc(n * vars * sizeof(int));
int k = 0;

for (unsigned int a = 0; a < aa.size(); aa++)
{
    for (unsigned int b = 0; b < bb.size(); bb++)
    {
        for (unsigned int c = 0; c < cc.size(); cc++)
        {
                inputs[k] = { aa[a], bb[b], cc[c] };
                k++;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried using `new` and looping the array for 2D but it didn't work for me.  What's the best way to structure this?

Comment: Please include the error message in the quesiton. If your error is too large then it is too large.... why do you **NEED** to use an `array` not `vector`?. Btw there is no good reason for mixing `std::array` and c-arrays. If you want a mxn array then use `std::array< std::array<int, n>,m>`

Comment: You're trying to allocate too much on the stack. So, don't.

Comment: you should show the real code that causes the behavior you describe. I doubt that the code you posted causes a runtime error, because `array<int, vars>` should be a compiler error

Comment: Allocating megabyte(s) of space on the stack is going to cause issues.  Consider dynamic or global memory instead.  Please include full functions as well as what you have isn't enough for us to offer any more info than this.

Comment: btw from your code it seems like you do not need the array at all, because you already have the data readily available and just want to fill the array with a huge number of duplicate data. If this example is demonstrative for your real code and you can explain why you think you need the array, I am certain that one can suggest a solution that does not require an array that large

Comment: looks like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you need that array for? What do you think you can do with that array that you cannot do with `aa`,`bb` and `cc` ?

Comment: 'I need to use an array', but you also tried new which means you don't need to use an array. You should explain what problem you are actually trying to solve, instead of asking for advice on what you think the answer is.

Comment: @ChrisMM I am aware of this. Not sure how to alloc to heap in this case.
@idclev463035818 I actually used `array<int, 3> in my code, but put this in the post.
I need an array because I'm using CUDA which doesn't accept vectors
@john I need to use the array but it this gives me a "stack overflow" error how should I allocate memory in this case? Thanks for all the replies!

Comment: Dynamic allocated can be done with `new`. `array<int, vars> *inputs = new array<int,val>[n]` … Not sure I'd recommend that though.

Comment: Thanks Chris that looks like it worked! Why would you not recommend it? What would be the best way to`delete` this? If you post an answer I would be happy to accept it

Comment: "actually used `array<int, 3>` in my code, but put this in the post." dont do that. Posting code and claiming that it causes a stack overflow when it does not causes confusion and potentially downvotes. Moreover, "I'm using CUDA which doesn't accept vectors" vectors have a `data()` method that returns a pointer to the underlying array. Your motivation to not use vectors is moot. You should include such information in the question

Comment: @mondego "*Why would you not recommend it?*" - because you should avoid using `new`/`new[]` directly in modern C++ coding. Use `std::make_unique()` instead, eg: `auto inputs = std::make_unique<array<int,val>[]>(n);` "*What would be the best way to `delete` this?*" - you would need to use `delete[]`, not `delete`, eg: `array<int, vars> *inputs = new array<int,val>[n]; ... delete[] inputs;` `std::unique_ptr` can handle both `delete` and `delete[]` for you, depending on whether it is holding a pointer to a single item or to an array.

Comment: did you read the link above? This is a schoolbook example of a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of asking for what you think is the solution (a monster sized array on the stack) you better tell us about the actual problem you are trying to solve (passing something to CUDA, currently not present in the question)

Comment: @mondego on a side note, `array<int, vars>` will not compile when `vars` is not a compile-time constant, which it is not in your example.

Comment: @mondego - Your operating system might have a way to increase the stack space limit. On Linux, look at command `ulimit -s ...`. Still, as mentioned by other commenters, this is probably second best compared to a) using `std::vector` and b) passing some `vec.data()` pointers to whatever CUDA API entry point which requires pointers.